# Why do I get two different transfer functions for the same gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, filter, transfer-function, homework

I'm trying to derive the expression for \$ A_X = \frac{V_X}{V_{IN}}\$ but I'm getting two different ones relatively to the \$KCL\$ I use to calculate it.

[image]

With \$ KCL \; A)\; -\frac{V_{IN}}{R_S} = \frac{V_{IN}-V_O}{R_F}\$
therefore with \$V_O = \left(1+\frac{R_F}{R_S} \right)V_{IN}\$ , if I use:

- \$KCL \; X)\; \frac{V_{IN}-V_X}{R_3}+sC\left(V_O-V_X\right) = \frac{V_X}{R_4}\$ ,
  then I get \$ R_4V_{IN}-R_4V_X + sCR_3 R_4 \left(1+\frac{R_F}{R_S} \right)V_{IN} - sCR_3 R_4V_X=R_3 V_X\$ ,
  therefore \$ A_X = \frac{V_X}{V_{IN}} = \frac{R_SR_4+sCR_3R_4\left( R_S+R_F\right)}{R_S\left(R_3+R_4 \right)+sCR_3R_4R_S} \$ .
- \$ KCL\;O)\; \frac{V_{IN}-V_O}{R_F}=sC\left(V_O-V_X\right)\$ ,
  then I get \$ V_{IN}-\left(1+\frac{R_F}{R_S} \right)V_{IN} = sCR_F\left(1+\frac{R_F}{R_S} \right)V_{IN}-sCR_FV_X\$ ,
  therefore \$ A_X = \frac{V_X}{V_{IN}} = \frac{1+sC\left(R_S+R_F\right)}{sCR_S}\$ .

I was thinking that maybe not considering the current that goes into the output of the op-amp when applying Kirchhoff's current law at the \$ O\$ node is an error thus resulting in the second expression being wrong, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Applying KCL at O isn't productive because you don't know either the output current of the opamp or the load current.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks! That's what I though. But now, if I wanted to calculate the impedance felt by the voltage source, how could I derive a third relationship between \$V_X\$ and \$ V_{IN}\$ without relying on the \$KCL\$ at \$O\$ ?

Comment: Your missing relationship is \$I_{in} = \dfrac{V_{in}-V_{x}}{R_{3}}\$.  Then the load on \$V_{in}\$ is \$\dfrac{V_{in}}{I_{in}} = \dfrac{V_{in}}{V_{in}-V_x} R_3\$

Comment: @RitterTree Actually, you get the same result if you also include the output node in your KCL. If you set up `va/rs+va/rf = vout/rf` and `vx/r4+vx/r3+vx*s*c = vout*s*c+vin/r3` and `vout/rf+vout*s*c = iout+vx*s*c+va/rf` and `va = vin` and solve for va, vx, iout, and vout then you will get vout/vin just as you got. It works fine to include the output amp's output current.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, right! Thanks!

Comment: @periblepsis Got it, thanks! So it was a mistake not to consider \$I_O\$ in the \$KCL\$ at \$O\$.

Comment: @periblepsis: It isn't productive to do that, because you're adding one equation and one unknown.  Doesn't change whether you can solve the system, just increases the amount of work you do.

Comment: @BenVoigt Read carefully what I wrote and why. I was responding to a point made in the question in the last paragraph.

Comment: @RitterTree There are different ways to solve most problems. I was only pointing out that including the output current of the opamp isn't necessarily wrong. When you are doing KCL for such an output node, then the output current is a valid part of that KCL. You may not care about the solution for the current. But the KCL wouldn't be complete without it when assuming an ideal opamp. (Non-ideal is another thing.)

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application of KCL at O accounts for currents in Rf and C, but not for op-amp output current, and so it isn't correct.

You can treat the op-amp output as a ground-referenced voltage source, with potential \$V_O\$, which allows you to draw the system of R3, R4 and C like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA1J4a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

KCL applied at X gets you:

$$ \frac{V_{IN}-V_X}{R_3} + (V_O-V_X)sC = \frac{V_X}{R_4} $$

As you stated, \$V_O = \left(1+\frac{R_F}{R_S}\right)V_{IN}\$, and you can substitute \$V_O\$ above with this expression for \$V_O\$ to obtain a potential \$V_X\$ in terms of only \$V_{IN}\$.